# React: event bubbling through nested components

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

Let's say I have nested components like this:

```
<root />
  <comp1 />
    <comp2 />
      <target id={this.props.id}>
        <div>click me</div>
```

I want to make clicking on target run a function on root:

```
//on root component
this.action = function(id){}
```

Do I need to do manually set a property on every component in the chain, like in the React tutorial example? [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/n47gckhr/light/)

```
<root />
  <comp1 clickHandler={this.action}/>
    <comp2 clickHandler={this.clickHandler}/>
      <target id={this.props.id} clickHandler={this.clickHandler} />
        <div onClick={this.props.clickHandler.bind(this, this.props.id)}>click me</div>
```

Or is there some way to bubble the events up like in normal DOM?

Comment: Events bubble up in React like they do in HTML: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-event-bubbling-capturing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the shorthand to pass props through to child components

```
<Component {...this.props} more="values" />
```

[Transferring props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html)

So in your case:

```
<root />
  <comp1 clickHandler={this.action}/>
    <comp2 {...this.props} />
      <target {...this.props} id={this.props.id} />
        <div onClick={this.props.clickHandler.bind(this, this.props.id)}>click me</div>
```

Comment: While {...this.props} works, it makes it really difficult to reason about what's get passed down components, after maintaining a project with hundreds of components this get dizzyingly impossible to track.

Comment: @Patrick you can try [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). It introduce a concept `selector`, which allow you select the props from a global data store instead of passing props from parent

Comment: Thx, redux is used for global state, plus its not what the question eas about. I just specifically stated that the spread operator is confusing at best when things get nested

Comment: I have not used react very long so take this with a grain of salt but this seems like an anti-pattern to me if you're trying to decouple your components and reuse them. This pattern makes them dependent upon being children of the parent object with specifically named properties.

Comment: This is smelly, today it has a name - prop drilling, and it is an anti pattern

Answer (score 39):

React supports Synthetic Events across it's Virtual DOM in both capturing and bubbling phases (as described here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

This means that you could put an onClick handler on any DOM element near the root and it should trigger for all Click events on the page:

```
<root>
  <div onClick={this.handleAllClickEvents}>
    <comp1>
      <comp2>
        <target>
          <div id={this.props.id}>click me</div>
```

However, since it will fire for *all* click events, you would need to disambiguate between them in the click handler (which makes for some pretty ugly code).

```
function handleAllClickEvents(event) {
  var target = event.relatedTarget;
  var targetId = target.id;
  switch(targetId) {
    case 'myBtn1':
      // handle myBtn1 click event
    case 'myBtn2':
      // handle myBtn2 click event
  }
}
```

This style of Event Delegation is actually what React does under the hood (https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation) so you have to ask yourself if that's what you really want to do.

Alternatively you might want to look at something like the Dispatcher pattern in Flux (https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html). It's a little bit more complicated to get going but it's a better solution overall.

Comment: I thought you aren't supposed to mutate props?

Comment: «for all Click events on the page» It more corect to say, for all descendants (inner nodes).

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/actions-and-the-dispatcher.html#content <-- this link does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distinguish which element was clicked at the end, you may use Event object and find there some interesting stuff, such as DOM element type.

```
<AnElement>
 <button onClick={e => this.eventHandler(e)}>Click me</button>
 <input type="text" onClick={e => this.eventHandler(e)}>Click me</input>

eventHandler = (e) => {
        console.log(e, e.nativeEvent.toElement.nodeName);
...}
```

And you get **button** or **input** depending on what you've clicked.
That's what i looked for for my project.

More over you may find a DOM tree in an array representation [image: array representation]

Hope it helps