# React, click on the parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a thing in React like this

```
<li id="my-id" onClick={this.handleClick}>
  <span>Something here</span>
  <i>Some italic text here</i>
</li>
```

Where I need to access the id of my LI.

```
handleClick(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target);
}
```

The thing is that when I click on the italic text, it console me the i element, not the li as it should.

Can someone explain me why, and how can I make onClick to return my li element?

Comment: "Why" is because this is how React works, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/32562118/438992. This is the same as how, say, jQuery works: the target is what's clicked on, `currentTarget` is where the handler was attached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need use `.currentTarget` instead of `.target`

```
handleClick(ev) {
  console.log(ev.currentTarget);
}
```

> `.currentTarget` refers to the element where event handler has been
>   attached to as opposed to `.target` which identifies the element on
>   which the event occurred.